# What is the probability of getting $8$ white marbles when $8$ marbles are selected without replacement from $5$ red and $10$ white marbles?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Problem:
A box contains $5$ red and $10$ white marbles. If $8$ marbles are to be chosen at random (without replacement),
determine the probability that all will be white.
Answer:
Let $p$ be the probability we seek.
\begin{align*}
p &=
 \left( \dfrac{ 10 } { 15 } \right) \left(  \dfrac{ 9 } { 14 } \right) \left(  \dfrac{ 8 } { 13 } \right)
 \left( \dfrac{ 7 } { 12 } \right) \left(  \dfrac{ 6 } { 11 } \right) \left(  \dfrac{ 5 } { 10 } \right)
 \left( \dfrac{ 4 } { 9 } \right) \left( \dfrac{ 3 } { 8 } \right)  \\
%
p &=
 \left( \dfrac{ 2 } { 3 } \right) \left(  \dfrac{ 9 } { 14 } \right) \left(  \dfrac{ 8 } { 13 } \right)
\left( \dfrac{ 7 } { 12 } \right) \left(  \dfrac{ 6 } { 11 } \right) \left(  \dfrac{ 1 } { 2 } \right)
\left( \dfrac{ 4 } { 9 } \right) \left( \dfrac{ 3 } { 8 } \right)  \\
%
p &= \dfrac{ 2(9)(8)(7)(6)(4)(9) } { 3(14)(13)(12)(11)(2)(9)(8) } \\
p &= \dfrac{ 9(8)(7)(6)(4)(9) } { 3(14)(13)(12)(11)(9)(8) }
 = \dfrac{ 8(7)(6)(4)(9) } { 3(14)(13)(12)(11)(8) } \\
p &= \dfrac{ 7(6)(4)(9) } { 3(14)(13)(12)(11) } =  \dfrac{ 6(4)(9) } { 3(2)(13)(12)(11) } \\
p &= \dfrac{ 324 }{ 10296 } = \dfrac{ 81 }{ 2574 } \\
p &= \dfrac{ 9 }{ 286 }
\end{align*}
The book's answer is $\dfrac{ 1 }{ 143 }$.
Where did I go wrong?

Based upon the comments I have gotten, I updated my solution. Here is an updated solution which I believe is correct:

Let $p$ be the probability we seek.
\begin{align*}
p &=
 \left( \dfrac{ 10 } { 15 } \right) \left(  \dfrac{ 9 } { 14 } \right) \left(  \dfrac{ 8 } { 13 } \right)
 \left( \dfrac{ 7 } { 12 } \right) \left(  \dfrac{ 6 } { 11 } \right) \left(  \dfrac{ 5 } { 10 } \right)
 \left( \dfrac{ 4 } { 9 } \right) \left( \dfrac{ 3 } { 8 } \right)  \\
%
p &=
 \left( \dfrac{ 2 } { 3 } \right) \left(  \dfrac{ 9 } { 14 } \right) \left(  \dfrac{ 8 } { 13 } \right)
\left( \dfrac{ 7 } { 12 } \right) \left(  \dfrac{ 6 } { 11 } \right) \left(  \dfrac{ 1 } { 2 } \right)
\left( \dfrac{ 4 } { 9 } \right) \left( \dfrac{ 3 } { 8 } \right)  \\
%
p &= \dfrac{ 2(9)(8)(7)(6)(4)(3) } { 3(14)(13)(12)(11)(2)(9)(8) } \\
p &= \dfrac{ 9(8)(7)(6)(4)(3) } { 3(14)(13)(12)(11)(9)(8) }
 = \dfrac{ 8(7)(6)(4)(3) } { 3(14)(13)(12)(11)(8) } \\
p &= \dfrac{ 7(6)(4)(3) } { 3(14)(13)(12)(11) } \\
p &= \dfrac{ 504 }{ 72072 } \\
p &= \dfrac{ 1 }{ 143 }
\end{align*}

Comment: Which part are you doing, a, b, or c?

Comment: I am doing part b. I will fix the post.

Comment: You have a (9) at the end of the numerator that should be a (3) at the very least.

Comment: In your second attempt, you could have simplified further once you reached $\frac{7 \cdot 6 \cdot 4 \cdot 3}{3 \cdot 14 \cdot 13 \cdot 12 \cdot 11}$.  Since $4 \cdot 3 = 12$, cancel a factor of $12$ from the numerator and denominator to get $\frac{7 \cdot 6}{3 \cdot 14 \cdot 13 \cdot 12 \cdot 11}$.  Since $14 = 7 \cdot 2$, cancel a $7$ to obtain $\frac{6}{3 \cdot 2  \cdot 13 \cdot 11}$.  Since $6 = 3 \cdot 2$, cancel a $6$ to obtain $\frac{1}{13 \cdot 11} = \frac{1}{143}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is more simply given by an instance of the hypergeometric distribution:
$$\frac{\binom50\binom{10}8}{\binom{15}8}=\frac{45}{6435}=\frac1{143}$$
Your initial form of the answer as a product of simple fractions is correct though – you just made a mistake simplifying it.

Comment: Could you tell me which line in my solution is wrong?

Comment: @Bob Please don't go the long way. Just compute the numerator and denominator separately.